# Dealing with state in a realtime messaging app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vue-component, vuex

I'm looking for some guidance with regards to managing state in a real-time messaging/chat app built with VueJS 2.

The app consists of several components which are outlined in the following diagram:

[image: VueJS realtime messaging app component tree]

So far, I've implemented displaying (fake) conversations. The App component contains an array with conversation objects. For each child component, the relevant data is passed using props. This is really simple and works like a charm.

**Now, I have to deal with actions/mutations from components deeply nested in the tree. For example, sending a message and appending it to the corresponding array of messages.**

I figured it would be as easy as dispatching a (global) event in the AppConversationChatWindowInput component and handling it in the App component. Boy was I wrong. Apparently, [this functionality was removed when Vue 2.0 was introduced](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced) in favor of Vuex. I'm not sure why it was removed, because in some situations this could be a perfectly reasonable way to deal with events.

I guess there are a couple of possible solutions:

1. **Passing the websocket connection to each child component.** This could technically work. The App would connect to the websocket server and pass this connection to its child components using props. When the user sends a message, it is echoed by the websocket server. The App component can listen for the message and append it to the array of messages.

   Regardless of the technical feasability, this feels like a crappy and hard-to-maintain archicture to me. In my opinion, no component other than the App should be aware of the websocket connection, let alone its concrete implementation.
2. **Manually bubbling up the event in each component in the chain.**
   This seems like a complete pain to maintain. Introduces a lot of needless complexity and failure points.
3. **Using a global event bus.**
   This is possible, but why should an input field depend upon a global event bus? I don't like unnecessary dependencies and coupling. It adds complexity and makes things harder to test.
4. **Using a global data store (Vuex).**
   See #3. Another dependency and added complexity. Also, *if* I would settle for Vuex, how would I retrieve data in my components? Do I pass it down using components (like I do now) or would a component deep down in the tree just grab it from the store directly? To me, it feels like the component knows a lot more than it should this way.

Any thoughts? What's the best way to handle state in my situation?

Comment: I think the complexity added with veux or redux far outweigh trying to have components manage their own state especially when component state depends on other components (like pausing a game when a menu is opened).  You cannot have menu communicate with game because the rule is an application rule (component should not be aware of this rule). An event store enables you to handle certain events at application level to implement such rules.

Comment: [Native events bubble](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components).

Comment: @RoyJ: How would I decide between Vue events and native events?

Comment: The advantage to native events is that they (can) bubble, which can be useful so that you don't have to propagate events up the parent chain. It can be convenient as long as you can reasonably expect the bottom-level widget to emit that event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bit of a disconnect between "I wanted to dispatch a global event" and "I don't want to use a global event bus." A global event bus is how you dispatch/broadcast a global event. It is, as you note, a good solution in some situations. It is not hard to set up when you need it, so there's no strong reason for it to be in core Vue.

You can create the bus as an [instance property on Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html#Simple-Example) so it is available to every component:

```
Vue.prototype.$globalEventBus = new Vue();
```

Where you would have had `vm.$dispatch(...)` you would do `vm.$globalEventBus.$emit(...)` and the receiving component can set up `vm.$globalEventBus.$on(...)`.

Alternatively, you could create a bus at the top level and pass it through the children as a prop. This avoids globals, and you don't have to worry about bubbling.

Finally, as I noted in my comment, native events bubble, and you can [catch them at any component higher up the chain](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components). You could catch the event(s) that send messages, or even [roll your own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) events to catch.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer! I was not aware that you can put the event bus as an instance property on Vue, nice. What would be your preferred solution?

Comment: I like the bus-as-prop, because it avoids globals.